# Why the sensitive data is showing in Cache.db of my Cordova Ionic App?

Tags: ios, cordova, ssl, ionic-framework

I have a *Cordova Ionic* iOS App. After login into application, user's data will be taken from the *WCF* web service and will be displayed in the app.

I am not saving the data which is taken from service in the app using methods like `window.localStorage.setItem(...)` etc. But the data is shown in the `cache.db` file( located at `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/JKHGJGJ-JHKJ-87789-JHKH-KJHJH8778`.

This causes to get data from outside the application which causes the security issue. Anybody have a solution to resolve this?

I am using `$http.post` method to get data from Service and the data is just showing in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I'd looked for an answer on the same subject. After doing some research, found this cordova plugin:

https://github.com/wongatech/cordova-disable-nsurl-cache/

My app still creates the Cache.db but nothing gets stored there. I don't know if that would be enough for you. In my case it is a cordova iOS app, I'm not using Ionic, but if you check the plugin's h file, you can see how it works.

*If you try to install the plugin following the Installation section of the readme file of the plugin you would get an error. Try cloning the git master